# Nvidia CUDA - passing struct by pointer

Tags: c, cuda, nvidia, memcheck, cuda-gdb

I have a problem with passing a pointer to the struct to the device function.
I want to create a struct in local memory (i know it's slow, it's just an example) and pass it to the other function by pointer. The problem is that when i debug it with memcheck on, i get error:

`Program received signal CUDA_EXCEPTION_1, Lane Illegal Address.
Switching focus to CUDA kernel 0, grid 1, block (0,0,0), thread (0,0,0), device 0, sm 7, warp 0, lane 0
0x0000000000977608 in foo (st=0x3fffc38) at test.cu:15
15 st->m_tx = 99;`

If I debug it without memcheck on, it works fine and gives expected results.
My OS is RedHat 6.3 64-bits with Kernel 2.6.32-220.
I use GTX680, CUDA 5.0 and compile the program with sm=30.

Code I used for testing this is below:

```
typedef struct __align__(8) {
    int m_x0;
    int m_tx;
} myStruct;

__device__ void foo(myStruct *st) {
    st->m_tx = 99;
    st->m_x0 = 123;
}
__global__ void myKernel(){
    myStruct m_struct ;
    m_struct.m_tx = 45;
    m_struct.m_x0 = 90;
    foo(&m_struct);
}
int main(void) {
    myKernel  <<<1,1 >>>();
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your device code won't survive dead code removal because nothing contributes to a write to global memory. I would be surprised if you are looking at anything other than a null kernel in this example.

Comment: I assume by "CUDA 5.0" you mean the CUDA 5.0 release candidate (and not the earlier preview)?

Answer (score 4):

Your example code is completely optimised away by the compiler because none of the code contributes to a global memory write. This is easily proved by compiling the kernel to a cubin file and disassembling the result with `cuobjdump`:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -Xptxas="-v" -cubin struct.cu 
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z8myKernelv' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z8myKernelv
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 2 registers, 32 bytes cmem[0]

$ cuobjdump -sass struct_dumb.cubin 

    code for sm_20
        Function : _Z8myKernelv
    /*0000*/     /*0x00005de428004404*/     MOV R1, c [0x1] [0x100];
    /*0008*/     /*0x00001de780000000*/     EXIT;
        .............................
```

ie. the kernel is completely empty. The debugger can't debug the code you want to investigate because it does not exist in what the compiler/assembler emitted. If we take a few liberties with your code:

```
typedef struct __align__(8) {
    int m_x0;
    int m_tx;
} myStruct;
__device__ __noinline__ void foo(myStruct *st) {
    st->m_tx = 99;
    st->m_x0 = 123;
}
__global__ void myKernel(int dowrite, int *output){
    myStruct m_struct ;
    m_struct.m_tx = 45;
    m_struct.m_x0 = 90;
    if (dowrite) {
        foo(&m_struct);
        output[threadIdx.x] = m_struct.m_tx + m_struct.m_x0;
    }
}
int main(void) {
    int * output;
    cudaMalloc((void **)(&output), sizeof(int));
    myKernel  <<<1,1 >>>(1, output);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    return 0;
}
```

and repeat the same compilation and disassembly steps, things look somewhat different:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -Xptxas="-v" -cubin struct_dumb.cu 
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z8myKerneliPi' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z8myKerneliPi
    8 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z3fooP8myStruct
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 5 registers, 40 bytes cmem[0]
$ /usr/local/cuda/bin/cuobjdump -sass struct_dumb.cubin 

    code for sm_20
        Function : _Z8myKerneliPi
    /*0000*/     /*0x00005de428004404*/     MOV R1, c [0x1] [0x100];
    /*0008*/     /*0x20105d034800c000*/     IADD R1, R1, -0x8;
    /*0010*/     /*0x68009de218000001*/     MOV32I R2, 0x5a;
    /*0018*/     /*0xb400dde218000000*/     MOV32I R3, 0x2d;
    /*0020*/     /*0x83f1dc23190e4000*/     ISETP.EQ.AND P0, pt, RZ, c [0x0] [0x20], pt;
    /*0028*/     /*0x00101c034800c000*/     IADD R0, R1, 0x0;
    /*0030*/     /*0x00109ca5c8000000*/     STL.64 [R1], R2;
    /*0038*/     /*0x000001e780000000*/     @P0 EXIT;
    /*0040*/     /*0x10011c0348004000*/     IADD R4, R0, c [0x0] [0x4];
    /*0048*/     /*0xc001000750000000*/     CAL 0x80;
    /*0050*/     /*0x00009ca5c0000000*/     LDL.64 R2, [R0];
    /*0058*/     /*0x84011c042c000000*/     S2R R4, SR_Tid_X;
    /*0060*/     /*0x90411c4340004000*/     ISCADD R4, R4, c [0x0] [0x24], 0x2;
    /*0068*/     /*0x0c201c0348000000*/     IADD R0, R2, R3;
    /*0070*/     /*0x00401c8590000000*/     ST [R4], R0;
    /*0078*/     /*0x00001de780000000*/     EXIT;
    /*0080*/     /*0x8c00dde218000001*/     MOV32I R3, 0x63;
    /*0088*/     /*0xec009de218000001*/     MOV32I R2, 0x7b;
    /*0090*/     /*0x1040dc8590000000*/     ST [R4+0x4], R3;
    /*0098*/     /*0x00409c8590000000*/     ST [R4], R2;
    /*00a0*/     /*0x00001de790000000*/     RET;
        ...............................
```

we get actual code in the assembler output. You might have more luck in the debugger with that.

Comment: I just tested your code and it gives me the same error from memcheck.

Answer (score 2):

I am from the CUDA developer tools team. When compiled for device side debug (i.e. -G), the original code will not be optimized out. The issue looks like a memcheck bug. Thank you for finding this. We will look into it.

Comment: The problem might be platform specific as I am unable to reproduce it locally (I compiled the code with -g -G).